# Drupal theme won't read CSS file

Tags: php, css, templates, drupal, themes

I'm currently working on a drupal theme but keep having problems with getting the theme to read the damn css file. I started off theming with the Framework theme, I tried organising the files on there for example creating a subdirectory to store the CSS file, change the setting in the .info file so it knows it's in the css folder, but it won't read the damn file.

Fast forward a few days and I've got 60% of my theme styled and layout-ed, so decided to port everything into a new theme folder rather than the Framework theme folder. Organised the folders and files, but again it won't read the CSS file whether I put it in a subdirectory or in the same directory as the .info file. It somehow worked once, but then went and hasn't worked again.

I've tried clearing the cache etc, but to no avail.

I'm working on a local wamp server. Drupal is latest version 7.

Any ideas how to fix this problem?

Thank you

Comment: Do you have Firefox/Firebug installed? By looking in the Net panel you should be able to check whether the file path is correct. Check this first and asjust accordingly if necessary.

Comment: checked permissions? Also please include the relevant lines from your .info file.

Comment: @mirzu this is the css line from .info - /*** CSS ***/
stylesheets[all][] = css/style.css

Comment: @Matt Just checked that in firebug all it shows is some css files for drupal core files or something, nothing related to my theme.

Answer (score 0):

Wich version of Drupal you are using? In Drupal 6 this works fine:

```
/* mytheme.info */
stylesheets[all][]   = assets/css/master.css
stylesheets[all][]   = assets/css/typo.css
```

This files are in my Theme folder

```
Folder: MYTHEME
   File: mytheme.info
   Folder: assets
       Folder: css
           File: master.css
           File: typo.css
```

Comment: I'm using drupal 7, i have similar folder structure to you except I dont have css folder located in assets, not sure what that does. Strange that for example the bartik theme uses the same structure as me yet it all works for it.

Comment: Maybe in your template.php file is something wrong. Initally i unset all css files: http://jsfiddle.net/KFT4r/ I use the assets folder to keep my directory clean. I put all my media files like, js, css or images within the folder. Just for organisation...

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late but maybe it will help someone else.

I'm using Drupal 7 and I attempted to add a javascript and stylesheet file in a custom module in the .info file.

module.always.js
  and
module.always.css

It would load the first but not the second. I even put the stylesheet above the script in the info file and it would still just load the first file. Thought it was the directory and tried adding quotes around the file paths but that did nothing. Also thought it was the extra . in the file name but that didn't matter either.

The only way I could get both files to load was to remove them from the .info file and add a drupal_add_js and drupal_add_css for these files in the module_init() function.

No clue why that is the case but at least there is a work around.